# If statement with multiple arguments not being met

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am creating an account system which logs the user in if the correct credentials have been used. Currently my code is the following

```
    n=0
    for row in StaffAccounts:
        potential_user = StaffAccounts[n]
        n=n+1
        potential_user2 = potential_user.split(',')
        if stop:
            print ("fail")
            break
        elif potential_user2[0] == staff_idv2 and potential_user2[1] == staff_passv2:
            print ("Success")
```

`StaffAccounts` is array which holds the user's username and password. `potential_user` then copies a row out of `StaffAccounts` (thus copying the username and password for one user), whilst `potential_user2` splits this string into 2 seperate elements so that it is stored like this `[username, password]` rather than this `[usernamepassword]`

Test Data:

`staff_idv2` = "Dominic"

`staff_passv2` = "Dom123"

The condition should be met when `staff_idv2` and `staff_passv2` find their correspondents within `potential_username2`. However, this does not occur. The condition simply does not get met.

Here is a screenshot of what the text file array `StaffAccounts` looks like

https://gyazo.com/022cb37d34220e3155f85c451da8836c

Comment: Which value has `stop` ? `None` ?

Comment: How was `StaffAccounts` created?  If it's the result of calling `.readlines()` on a file, note that it will have newline characters at the end of each line.

Comment: it was. I found a way to avoid getting those \n's, which is written in a different function. Please note that when i print potential_user2, it gives me the expected result. It is just the condition that is not for some reason being met.